# Multidimensional vector problem in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Can someone please explain why I can't populate a multidimensional vector once its been established and recommend a workaround? See error below:

```
int listcount=3;
public void splitlist(Atom[] args){
    Vector v=new Vector();
    for(int i=0;i<listcount;i++){ //create vectors:
        v.add(new Vector());
    }
    for(int i=0; i<args.length;i++){//populate vectors: 
        int mod=i%listcount;
        v[mod].add(args[i]); //<<<error here: array required, but java.util.Vector found
    }
    for(int i=0;i<listcount;i++){//output vectors:
        outlet(i,toAtom(v[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use generics.

Comment: I agree, generics are many years old and would make this code much easier to read and understand. It would also make the error jump off the page at the reader. I also recommend using `List<T>` variables storing `ArrayList<T>`. which is equivalent to `Vector<T>` without the synchronization. This question smells like a 10 year old tutorial or "learn Java in  24 hours" book.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll look into generics. I'm experienced in higher level languages but this is my first venture into java so I'm having teething problems with the issues java's strict type casting brings to the table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int listcount=3;
public void splitlist(Atom[] args){
    Vector v=new Vector();
    for(int i=0;i<listcount;i++){ //create vectors:
        v.add(new Vector());
    }
    for(int i=0; i<args.length;i++){//populate vectors: 
        int mod=i%listcount;
        ((Vector)v.get(mod)).add(args[i]); //<<<error here: array required, but java.util.Vector found
    }
    for(int i=0;i<listcount;i++){//output vectors:
        outlet(i,toAtom(v.get(i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @amol. Could you explain why I still get an error? `cannot find symbol symbol : method add(com.cycling74.max.Atom) location: class java.lang.Object` I assume v.get(mod) returns the vector at the index 'mod'? If so why is the add() method throwing an error?

Comment: edited. it should work now. (John Gaughan is correct about using generics though)

Comment: Thanks @Amol - Works great now. I'll definitely look into generics. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `[]` operator on a `Vector`, which is not allowed.  You should replace it with a call to the `get(index)` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a Vector like an array.

Instead of:

```
v[mod]
```

Do:

```
v.get(mod)
```

Comment: Thanks! New error:
`cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(com.cycling74.max.Atom)
location: class java.lang.Object`

Comment: @cronoklee, the error message is clear, the method add can't be found on the Atom class.

Comment: @jzd I understand the message but I dont get why it's calling the add method on Atom? I'm using v.get[mod] which should return a vector should it not? Sorry Im new to java and type casting is killing me!

Comment: @Cronoklee, no the get method gets the element at that location. I would suggest learning to navigate the API that has all the descriptions and details for standard classes and methods. It is very helpful.

Comment: @jzd is the element at that location not also vector? Im working with a vector full of vectors right?

Comment: @Cronoklee, the v variable is a vector full of vectors but your error message indicates you might be accessing the args variable instead.